# Send params to DrawerNavigation contentComponent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

basically i have a `StackNavigator` nested in a `DrawerNavigator`.

What i want is to use the `contentComponent` of `DrawerNavigator` to display the loged in user avatar and name, something like the image below

Just to mention im not using redux or something like that.

[image]

I have a `InitializerScrren` which is reponsible for cheking the loged user and send it to the right place, login screen or home screen, iam using firebase too, so i ended up with this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    firebase.auth.listenForAuth((evt)=> {
        var initialRouteName = routesIds.SCREEN_TUTORIAL;
        var logedUser = null;
        if(evt.authenticated) {
            console.log('User details', evt.user);
            logedUser = evt.user;
            initialRouteName = routesIds.MAIN_DRAWER;
        }
        this.props.navigation.dispatch({type:'Reset', actions: [{type:'Navigate', routeName:initialRouteName, params:{user:logedUser}}], index:0});
    });
}
```

My `DrawerNavigator` config is this:

```
var drawerConfig = {
    drawerWidth: 250,
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    contentComponent: props => {
        console.log('contentComponent');
        console.log(props);
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View>
                    <View style={{paddingVertical: 20, paddingHorizontal: 15, backgroundColor:'#000'}}>
                        <Text style={{color:'#FFF'}}>avatar, Loged in User Name</Text>
                    </View>
                    <DrawerView.Items {...props} />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    },

    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: cssDefaults.colorPrimary,
        inactiveTintColor: cssDefaults.textColor,
        style: {
            marginVertical: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: let me know if some redux solution work for you

Comment: forget to mention, im not using redux

Comment: any solution since ?

Comment: @AlainIb nope, but this project is abandoned for now. And is much better and easier to learn redux or mobx to do this.So when i return to it will refactor somethings.